# How to check app is in ideal state in ios sdk

Tags: ios, iphone

Is there any to find that the user is not doing any activity in the app while the app is in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .inactive
```

other cases

```
case active

case inactive

case background
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [thread](https://gist.github.com/KingOfBrian/365998). Ii will wrapp with a UIWindow subclass which is going to send notification. You can use delegate for more effective.